# How to convert JavaScript code from HTML in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, paypal

I am looking at PayPal's documentation to implement their service, and I see this HTML code with JavaScript How can I do this in angularjs? separating javascript from HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Ensures optimal rendering on mobile devices -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!-- Optimal Internet Explorer compatibility -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: '77.44'
              }
            }]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id);
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide with samples for [Angular and Angular 2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/#2-add-the-code).